# How to declare and initialize a Char Array correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I know that the proper way to initialize a char array is as follows:

```
char sentence[256]={0};
cin.getline(sentence,256);
```

But can you please help me understand what is going on when we declare a char array as a pointer on char and then initialize it using `cin.getline` like this:

```
char* sentence;
cin.getline(sentence,256);
```

I know that the second way is bad since my code is going crazy.

Comment: Wouldn't `std::string sentence; std::getline(std::cin, sentence);` be better?

Comment: A pointer is **not** an array!

Answer (score 1):

```
char* sentence;  
cin.getline(sentence,256);  // wrong
```

You can't do that because your pointer `sentence` is not initialized and therefore cannot be used as input. Using a pointer without initializing causes undefined behavior.

Stick to your 1st method (using array). Otherwise, you need to `new` to dynamically allocate for your pointer - and then must remember to `delete` it after usage.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x it was originally tagged with both C/C++